# Show number of visits in the last 24 hours, broken down by the hour

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing a timestamp in a mysql table every time somebody visits the site for the first time.

I wind up with data that looks like this:

```
2009-08-02 04:08:27
2009-08-02 04:07:47
2009-08-02 05:58:13
2009-08-02 06:28:23
2009-08-02 06:34:22
2009-08-02 08:23:21
2009-08-02 09:38:56
```

What Im wanting to do with this data is create a count of visits that fall into each hour. So in the example above I would arrive at the 4th hour having 2 visits, the 5th hour = 1, 6th hour 2, 8th hour 1 etc.

I thought the best way to do this, would be to do a for statement like so:

```
// a 24 hour loop
for($i = 24; $i > -1; $i--) {

    // the query for each hour
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM visits WHERE (DATE(added) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL ' . $i . ' HOUR))'

$res = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);  


    // store the number of rows for this loop in the array
    $visits[] = $count;
}
```

That seems logical to me... but for some reason... its definitely not working.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about doing it in only one query, using a group by clause ?

Something like this would probably do :

```
select HOUR(added), count(*) as nbr
from visits
where added between '2009-07-14' and '2009-07-15'
group by HOUR(added)
order by HOUR(added)
```

*(of course, you might need to adapt some things, like the dates)*

It would make your DB server work more for that query than for the others your proposed... But only one query, and not 24 -- which is a good thing.

On the other side, you'd have less data going from the DB server to the PHP server ; which is great, especially if the table is big !

Then, on the PHP side, you'll have to "reconstruct" the full date, as this query will only get you the hours.

Comment: i just wanted to add, a little problem with the above method compared to what i was doing is that i'm creating 2 arrays. 1 with the hour names in it, 1 with the count of visits in that hour.

Using the method here Pascal, I get hours missing if there weren't visits on the hour like so:
"12AM","01AM","04AM","05AM","07AM","08AM","09AM","11AM","12PM","02PM","03PM","04PM","05PM","07PM","08PM","09PM","10PM","11PM"

and visits:
10,1,19,3,1,3,1,3,10,1,1,3,1,6,1,2,2,4

So there are 18 I think coming out, which means 4 hours of the 24 had no visits. Ideally, I'd like to retrieve count 0 for empty hours

Comment: A trick I used to do for this particular problem was create a hours table, which contains values from 0 to 23, and then outer join the query with this table to fill in the blanks. It's a dirty little trick, but it works pretty fine.

Comment: @OmerGertel : that'd be a solution ; but it might be better performance-speaking to just iterate over the results in PHP, and add the "missing hours" (yeah, that means a bit of PHP code to "patch" the resulset before using it, I admit)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
SELECT hour(added), count(*) 
FROM visits 
WHERE added >= CURRENT_DATE()-1
GROUP BY hour(added)
```

[Hour(time)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour): "Returns the hour for time. The range of the return value is 0 to 23 for time-of-day values",